# FFMPEG ignores "-shortest"

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG to overlay one video on another. It works, but the "-shortest" instruction is ignored.

This is the code:

```
ffmpeg -i "D:\Underlay.avi" -i "D:\Overlay.avi" -filter_complex \
[1:v]colorkey=0xFFFFFF:0.01:0.0[KeyedOverlay];\
[0:v][KeyedOverlay]overlay[Composite] \
-map [Composite] -c:v png -shortest "D:\Composite.avi"
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there an alternative method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both videos are being combined into a single video. Your output only has one video stream, so `-shortest` does nothing because it has no other streams to compare duration.

Use the [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) specific `shortest` option instead:

```
ffmpeg -i "D:\Underlay.avi" -i "D:\Overlay.avi" -filter_complex "[1:v]colorkey=0xFFFFFF:0.01:0.0[KeyedOverlay];[0:v][KeyedOverlay]overlay=shortest=1:format=auto[Composite]" -map "[Composite]" -c:v png "D:\Composite.avi"
```

I also added `format=auto` so your overlay may look better.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your overlay ends with the first video, simply insert

> **shortest=1**

within your overlay filter in the filtergraph, like so:

```
...overlay=...:shortest=1:enable='between(n\,start_frame\,end_frame)'...
```

This tells FFmpeg to end the overlay when the shortest input (typically your main video) concludes.

[Source FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Commands-128)